# Mongo DB - Selection for OR Operator

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query, logical-operators

I am trying to fetch documents with score greater than 90 or less than 50. I know the correct query to fetch the document, which is the first one. I just want to know what does the second query do (Which I know is incorrect). It fetches the doc, but I don't understand what it does.

```
1. db.subjects.find( { $or : [{"score" : { $lt : 50 }}, {"score" : { $gt : 90}}] } )

2. db.subjects.find( { $or : [{"score" : { $lt : 50 }, "score" : { $gt : 90}}] } )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that duplicate key are allowed in JSON document so the second query is the same as:

```
db.subjects.find( { $or : [{ "score" : { $gt : 90 } } ] })
```

or better

```
db.subjects.find( { "score" : { $gt : 90 } })
```

So if you check your query result you will see that it only returns only those documents where "score" is greater than `90`